# Sticky td (headers) with rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table, sticky

I would like to create **rowspan** on my **sticky header** but can't get it work.

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/x62v5ea8/1/

What i need is to connect first and second **td** in 'Header 1'

Can someone help me with this problem ?

HTML

```
<div class="my-wrapper">
    <div class="my-scroller">
        <table class="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="my-sticky-col">Header 1</th>
                    <th class="my-sticky-col2">Header 2</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <th>6</th>
                    <th>7</th>
                    <th>8</th>
                    <th>9</th>
                    <th>10</th>
                    <th>11</th>
                    <th>12</th>
                    <th>13</th>
                    <th>14</th>
                    <th>15</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" class="my-sticky-col">A</td>
                    <td class="my-sticky-col2">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="my-sticky-col">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="my-sticky-col2">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="my-sticky-col">C</td>
                    <td class="my-sticky-col2">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.myTable {
    border: none;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.myTable thead th {
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: none;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.myTable tbody td {
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.myTable tbody td, .myTable thead th {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.my-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.my-scroller {
    margin-left: 283px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}
.myTable .my-sticky-col {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    width: 120px;
}
.myTable .my-sticky-col2 {
    border-right: solid 1px #000;
    left: 142px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Your class my-sticky-col is making the rowspan fail due to position: absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is actually working correctly. You are not seeing the `rowspan` working because the `absolute` positioning that is used for the sticky header. I updated your JS Fiddle with a few tweeks so you can see what is going on. http://jsfiddle.net/x62v5ea8/2/

You can see in the HTML I commented out the cell that will used by the `rowspan` and added a `.test` class with a height and background color so you can see that the cell is now fully expanding. Alternatively you can remove the `position: absolute` and you see the same results but your header wont be sticky anymore.